# Is there an easy way to get the namespace of an LWC component (without calling Apex)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, namespace

**Use Case**: I want to be able to debug even JS resources, but when the managed package is installed I want to use the minified/obfuscated version of the JS library.

**Basic idea**: For the purpose, I am planning to check if the current namespace is 'c' to load unminified version and when it's different to load the minified one.

Any ideas if there is some other way besides calling Apex?
Also, would that be a security issue?

**Update:** For Aura I see that there is this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/184217/128410):

Comment: In Aura you have to explicitly use the package namespace prefix, not `c:` otherwise you get an error when creating a package version. I *suspect* that LWC automatically translates the `c:` prefix in LWC templates to the package namespace on deployment or transpiling - though not 100% sure on this. I suggest this because references to LWCs in flows automatically use the actual package namespace for the component. You can take a look at the JS sent to your browser to see.